# List of usable ogr-drivers for PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, ogr

When using the following PyQGIS line, I write a layer as a CSV into an output path.

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV",
                                        layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

I would like to write it as type "TXT". What are alternative ogr drivers than "CSV"? Perhabs there is a list of all available ogr drivers?

Unfortunately, the PyQGIS [Documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) doesn't give me any options.

Comment: What's wrong with CSV? It contains just plain text and you can rename it as .TXT if you wish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quickest way is to look on the [OGR formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) page or ask `ogrinfo`:

```
ogrinfo --formats | sort


  AeronavFAA -vector- (rov): Aeronav FAA
  AmigoCloud -vector- (rw+): AmigoCloud
  ARCGEN -vector- (rov): Arc/Info Generate
  AVCBin -vector- (rov): Arc/Info Binary Coverage
  AVCE00 -vector- (rov): Arc/Info E00 (ASCII) Coverage
  BNA -vector- (rw+v): Atlas BNA
  CAD -raster,vector- (rovs): AutoCAD Driver
  Carto -vector- (rw+): Carto
  Cloudant -vector- (rw+): Cloudant / CouchDB
  CouchDB -vector- (rw+): CouchDB / GeoCouch
  CSV -vector- (rw+v): Comma Separated Value (.csv)
  CSW -vector- (ro): OGC CSW (Catalog  Service for the Web)
  DGN -vector- (rw+v): Microstation DGN
  DXF -vector- (rw+v): AutoCAD DXF
  EDIGEO -vector- (rov): French EDIGEO exchange format
  EEDA -vector- (ro): Earth Engine Data API
  ElasticSearch -vector- (rw+): Elastic Search
  ESRIJSON -vector- (rov): ESRIJSON
  ESRI Shapefile -vector- (rw+v): ESRI Shapefile
  Geoconcept -vector- (rw+v): Geoconcept
  GeoJSONSeq -vector- (rw+v): GeoJSON Sequence
  GeoJSON -vector- (rw+v): GeoJSON
  Geomedia -vector- (ro): Geomedia .mdb
  GeoRSS -vector- (rw+v): GeoRSS
  GFT -vector- (rw+): Google Fusion Tables
  GMLAS -vector- (rwv): Geography Markup Language (GML) driven by application schemas
  GML -vector- (rw+v): Geography Markup Language (GML)
  GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
  GPSBabel -vector- (rw+): GPSBabel
  GPSTrackMaker -vector- (rw+v): GPSTrackMaker
  GPX -vector- (rw+v): GPX
  HTF -vector- (rov): Hydrographic Transfer Vector
  HTTP -raster,vector- (ro): HTTP Fetching Wrapper
  Idrisi -vector- (rov): Idrisi Vector (.vct)
  Interlis 1 -vector- (rw+v): Interlis 1
  Interlis 2 -vector- (rw+v): Interlis 2
  JML -vector- (rw+v): OpenJUMP JML
  JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
  KML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
  LIBKML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (LIBKML)
  MapInfo File -vector- (rw+v): MapInfo File
  MBTiles -raster,vector- (rw+v): MBTiles
  Memory -vector- (rw+): Memory
  MSSQLSpatial -vector- (rw+): Microsoft SQL Server Spatial Database
  MVT -vector- (rw+v): Mapbox Vector Tiles
  MySQL -vector- (rw+): MySQL
  NAS -vector- (rov): NAS - ALKIS
  netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Network Common Data Format
  NGW -raster,vector- (rw+s): NextGIS Web
  ODBC -vector- (rw+): ODBC
  ODS -vector- (rw+v): Open Document/ LibreOffice / OpenOffice Spreadsheet 
  OGR_DODS -vector- (ro): OGR_DODS
  OGR_GMT -vector- (rw+v): GMT ASCII Vectors (.gmt)
  OGR_OGDI -vector- (ro): OGDI Vectors (VPF, VMAP, DCW)
  OGR_PDS -vector- (rov): Planetary Data Systems TABLE
  OGR_SDTS -vector- (rov): SDTS
  OGR_VRT -vector- (rov): VRT - Virtual Datasource
  OpenAir -vector- (rov): OpenAir
  OpenFileGDB -vector- (rov): ESRI FileGDB
  OSM -vector- (rov): OpenStreetMap XML and PBF
  PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
  PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
  PGDUMP -vector- (w+v): PostgreSQL SQL dump
  PGeo -vector- (ro): ESRI Personal GeoDatabase
  PLSCENES -raster,vector- (ro): Planet Labs Scenes API
  PostgreSQL -vector- (rw+): PostgreSQL/PostGIS
  REC -vector- (ro): EPIInfo .REC 
  S57 -vector- (rw+v): IHO S-57 (ENC)
  SEGUKOOA -vector- (rov): SEG-P1 / UKOOA P1/90
  SEGY -vector- (rov): SEG-Y
  Selafin -vector- (rw+v): Selafin
  SOSI -vector- (ro): Norwegian SOSI Standard
  SQLite -vector- (rw+v): SQLite / Spatialite
  SUA -vector- (rov): Tim Newport-Peace's Special Use Airspace Format
  SVG -vector- (rov): Scalable Vector Graphics
  SXF -vector- (rov): Storage and eXchange Format
  TIGER -vector- (rw+v): U.S. Census TIGER/Line
  TopoJSON -vector- (rov): TopoJSON
  UK .NTF -vector- (rov): UK .NTF
  VDV -vector- (rw+v): VDV-451/VDV-452/INTREST Data Format
  VFK -vector- (ro): Czech Cadastral Exchange Data Format
  Walk -vector- (ro): Walk
  WAsP -vector- (rw+v): WAsP .map format
  WFS3 -vector- (ro): OGC WFS 3 client (Web Feature Service)
  WFS -vector- (rov): OGC WFS (Web Feature Service)
  XLS -vector- (ro): MS Excel format
  XLSX -vector- (rw+v): MS Office Open XML spreadsheet
  XPlane -vector- (rov): X-Plane/Flightgear aeronautical data
```

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of link I've been looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python bindings to get all available drivers:

```py
from osgeo import ogr
[ogr.GetDriver(i).GetDescription() for i in range(ogr.GetDriverCount())]
```